# static field using reflection in metro app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, system.reflection

I am trying to get a static field info into metro app and I don't find a way to do that.

I have tried:
- type.GetRuntimeField
- typeInfo.GetDeclaredField in a loop to delve into every parent types

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the field info from the specified name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The source type</param>
        /// <param name="fieldName">The name of the field</param>
        /// <returns>The field info if found, null otherwise</returns>
        public static FieldInfo GetField(this Type type, string fieldName)
        {
            var currentType = type;
            FieldInfo result = null;
            while (result == null && currentType != null)
            {
                var typeInfo = currentType.GetTypeInfo();
                result = typeInfo.GetDeclaredField(fieldName);
                currentType = typeInfo.BaseType;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

... am I missing something or is there anyway to get a static field on a type using reflection in metro app?....

**edit**:
Well, I am so sorry for those who have waste time on this question, Dependency properties defined in the framework are actualy not readonly static fields, they are static properties... As I usualy declare my dps as field, I didn't consider the fact that form example FrameworkElement.Width could be a property...

So here is the code I used to get fields and property info:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the field info from the specified name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The source type</param>
    /// <param name="fieldName">The name of the field</param>
    /// <returns>The field info if found, null otherwise</returns>
    public static FieldInfo GetField(this Type type, string fieldName)
    {
        var currentType = type;
        FieldInfo result = null;
        while (result == null && currentType != null)
        {
            var typeInfo = currentType.GetTypeInfo();
            result = typeInfo.GetDeclaredField(fieldName);
            currentType = typeInfo.BaseType;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the property info from the specified name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The source type</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property</param>
    /// <returns>The field info if found, null otherwise</returns>
    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty(this Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        var currentType = type;
        PropertyInfo result = null;
        while (result == null && currentType != null)
        {
            var typeInfo = currentType.GetTypeInfo();
            result = typeInfo.GetDeclaredProperty(propertyName);
            currentType = typeInfo.BaseType;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static DependencyProperty GetDependencyProperty(this DependencyObject dependencyObject, string propertyName)
    {
        var dependencyPropertyName = propertyName + "Property";
        var type = dependencyObject.GetType();
        var fieldInfo = type.GetField(dependencyPropertyName);
        if (fieldInfo == null)
        {
            var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(dependencyPropertyName);
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                return propertyInfo.GetValue(dependencyObject) as DependencyProperty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(dependencyObject);
            return value as DependencyProperty;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Regards,
Charles

Comment: I don't have experience with reflection in WinRT, but if it's anything like Silverlight, you may not be able to access it if its accessibility normally does not allow access. If it's `private`, try making it `public` and give it another shot.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It is actualy a public static field (a dependencyProperty)

Comment: I have no problem in a test app of running `GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("YOUR_FIELD_NAME")` to get a static field. Can you post a _complete_ and simple program that demonstrates this problem? Please include the class with the static field you're using and how you are calling your `GetField` method.

Comment: Can you post the outline of the field you are trying to return?

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, and sorry for the waste time, I tried with a custom static field, and it works, then I checkd the "WidthProperty" definition in FrameworkElement and I realized it was actualy a Property...